# Is there a reference for the SharePoint XSLT extension functions?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, rss, web-parts, dataview

There are a couple of different .NET XSLT functions that I see used in the out of the box SharePoint web parts (RSS Viewer and Data View web part).

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"  
    xmlns:rssaggwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/rssagg/runtime"
    ...>
    ...
    <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>  
    <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(link))}">More...</a>
    ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where can I find a reference that describes all of the extension functions that SharePoint provides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been wanting more info on ddwrt as well. The most information I have been able to find is from Serge van den Oever that was later turned into the MSDN article referenced in the previous answer.

http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2005/01/03/345535.aspx

As he noted in his blog post, this article contains some info that was censored in the MSDN article.

Other than this article, there is very little written on the topic. It unfortunately appears that scouring existing generated code (such as the xsl in DataForm web parts) is the best technique to learn more at present.

Comment: Another good link on DDWRT options, this page is part 14 but has back links to all the other parts at the top. http://sympmarc.com/2010/03/09/unlocking-the-mysteries-of-data-view-web-part-xsl-tags-part-14-%E2%80%93-miscellaneous-ddwrt-namespace-functions/

Answer (score 1):

Here is some documentation I found that describes the ddwrt (http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime) namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx

Comment: still looking for an exhaustive reference

Answer (score 1):

Good question +1

See also

[SharePoint Data View Web Part Extension Functions in the ddwrt Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143%28office.11%29.aspx) 
by Serge van den Oever

Answer (score 1):

Serge's article points to Microsoft.SharePoint, where you can find the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages namespace. In there, you can find the DdwRuntime and the BaseDdwRuntime. There, you can find all of the ddwrt functions. I used a decompiler to look this up.